# Normalization of wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am a beginner in the field of Quantum Mechanics. I was reading the book of SP KUILA (Vol-II) on Engineering Physics. There I came across this line:

> *But since according to the condition of normalisation, $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ψ^*ψdx=1,$$  $$ψ^*=0$$ at x=+∞ and x=-∞*.

I did not understand why it is zero.
Please explain.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331976/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/679585/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) = 0$$
is a necessary condition for the integral
$$ \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx f(x) $$
to converge.

Apply this to $f(x) = |\Psi(x)|$ to get $|\Psi(\pm \infty)| = 0$, which can only be true if $\Psi(\pm \infty) = \Psi^{*}(\pm \infty) = 0$.